# How to externalize app configuration in Android App?

Tags: android

I am working with an Android App for Android 9 and my customer needs to externalize the configuration.
Currently, I give to him a prod APK that I especially build for prod usage with prod environment variables built with buildConfigField.
But it contains sensitive data in prod that I should not see, so I need to be able to build a prod APK then let him to configure the app through an external file (or any other solution).

What is the best practice for this case please ?

Comment: What does "the configuration" mean?

Comment: Configuration specific to app, It may be API endpoints, API secret, authentication key. Confidential information used to authenticate thhrough an API on network.